# R count column for each element, no matter redundancy

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry if I'm asking something obvious, but couldn't find anything similar.

Suppose I have this data:

```
a<-c('blue','blue','green','red','black',
     'white','blue','blue','blue','red',
     'black','white','blue','green','red',
     'black','white','white','black','white',
     'blue','white','blue','green')
```

and would like to have it in a data frame, with a column that summarizes the number of times each element appears in the whole vector, no matter if it's redundant. Something like this:

```
data.frame(a=c('blue','blue','green','red',
               'black','white','blue','blue',
               'blue','red','black','white',
               'blue','green','red','black',
               'white','white','black','white',
               'blue','white','blue','green'),
           b=c(8,8,3,3,4,6,8,8,8,3,4,
               6,8,3,3,4,6,6,4,6,8,6,8,3))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the functions tapply and ave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289258/what-is-the-difference-between-the-functions-tapply-and-ave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of the question linked by mnel, here's how to do this with ave:

```
data.frame(a, b=ave(seq_along(a), a, FUN=length))
       a b
1   blue 8
2   blue 8
3  green 3
4    red 3
5  black 4
6  white 6
7   blue 8
8   blue 8
9   blue 8
10   red 3
11 black 4
12 white 6
13  blue 8
14 green 3
15   red 3
16 black 4
17 white 6
18 white 6
19 black 4
20 white 6
21  blue 8
22 white 6
23  blue 8
24 green 3
```

This uses a bogus numeric vector, and just takes the length for each value.

It might make more sense to take a vector of `1`'s and take the sum:

```
data.frame(a, b=ave(rep(1, length(a)), a, FUN=sum))
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for these quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate frequencies

```
counts<-table(a)
```

Turn it into a data.frame

```
df<-as.data.frame(counts)
```

For each row in df, repeat it Freq times

```
df2 <- sapply(1:nrow(df), 
   function(x) df[rep(x, df$Freq[x]), ],simplify = FALSE)
```

Convert the list of data frames into one data frame

```
df3<-do.call("rbind", df2)

df3
    a Freq
black    4
black    4
black    4
black    4
 blue    8
 blue    8
 blue    8
 blue    8
 blue    8
 blue    8
 blue    8
 blue    8
green    3
green    3
green    3
  red    3
  red    3
  red    3
white    6
white    6
white    6
white    6
white    6
white    6
```

Comment: If you're using `table` you could also do: `data.frame(a,b=table(a)[a])`